# Why is my Image Icon not showing up in my JFrame?

Tags: java

[image][image]I am trying to display an image icon PNG, I have properly referred to the file called "logo.png" inside the project folder and set the icon as seen below. I'm not sure where I went wrong as I followed this tutorial starting around minute 14 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kmgo00avvEw&t=298s), I have made sure the code was correct but I'm still unable to get the image to appear beside the text when I run the code in Eclipse.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class mainClass {
    
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // JFrame is a GUI frame to add components to
        
        //JLabel a GUI display area for a string of texts and image.

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel(); //creates JLabel
        label.setText("Welcome to Magic Shape"); //sets text for label
        label.setIcon(image);
        
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates JFrame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //close operations when...
        frame.setSize(500, 500); //sets size of JFrame (can resize)
        frame.setTitle("Magic Shape"); //title of Program
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
        frame.add(label); //adds label
        
        
        
        
        

        
        

        
    }
}
```

Comment: The _Arguments_ tab in the _Run Configurations_ window shows the working directory. By the way, can you view the image `logo.png` in an image viewer, like _Preview_?

Comment: Ye I can view the image, I'll update the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
package be.project.jframe;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // JFrame is a GUI frame to add components to

        //JLabel a GUI display area for a string of texts and image.

        InputStream stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/be/project/jframe/icons/400.png");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(stream));
        JLabel jLabelObject = new JLabel("Welcome to Magic Shape");
        jLabelObject.setIcon(icon);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates JFrame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //close operations when...
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setTitle("Magic Shape"); //title of Program
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
        frame.add(jLabelObject); //adds label
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: if you initialized the window from another class(which is not static), you can do this (example in a constructor): `InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/be/project/jframe/icons/400.png");`

Comment: ```URL urlIcon = getClass().getResource("icons/400.png");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(urlIcon));
        JLabel jLabelObject = new JLabel("Welcome to Magic Shape");
        jLabelObject.setIcon(img);```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, Java searches for the file `logo.png` in the working directory. The working directory is the value returned by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. If Java does not find the file, it essentially creates a null icon and that's why you aren't seeing the icon.

Just make sure you put the file in the correct directory.

Refer to the following.

- [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)
- [Retrieving Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html)
- [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: When I put System.getProperty("user.dir") into my class, it returned the correct directory. I'm confused why it still creates this null icon.

Comment: @WIlliamWang what platform are you on? Windows? MacOS? linux? In your Eclipse run configuration, have you indicated the default working directory? Can you post a screen capture of _Package Explorer_ view in Eclipse? If you can, then also indicate the relevant Java project.

Comment: I'm working on MacOs and put the run configurations on the original post above, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the png file is placed at current working directory:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: When I add it to my code it returns the correct working directory, it says "/Users/williamwang/eclipse-workspace/Texas." Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it's right. Now put the `logo.png` file there. And run the code

Comment: The logo file has always been placed inside the project.